# How can I override quarkus.security.users.embedded.users on docker run command line?

Tags: quarkus

I have a quarkus based webapp that uses **Basic Authentication** with **Embedded Realm Configuration**. The webapp runs in a docker container. The authentication properties are specified in **application.properties** like this:

```
quarkus.http.auth.basic=true

quarkus.security.users.embedded.enabled=true
quarkus.security.users.embedded.plain-text=true
quarkus.security.users.embedded.users.test=mypass
quarkus.security.users.embedded.roles.test=admin
```

I would like to override **quarkus.security.users.embedded.users.test** to specify a password at docker runtime.

I tried to do this by overriding the quarkus property using an environment variable at docker runtime.

```
docker run -p 9999:9999 -e QUARKUS_SECURITY_USERS_EMBEDDED_USERS_TEST=newpasswd mywebapp
```

This does not work. When I access mywebapp using http://locahost:9999 I must login using **test/mypass**. I expected to login using **test/newpasswd**.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you [report an issue](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/new/choose) for this problem. While Quarkus won't be able to "enumerate" any new users from environment variables (the correct property names cannot be deduced), I think it should still be possible to override the password of a user that has already been specified in `application.properties` using an environment variable like you try to do.

Comment: Thanks @knutwannheden. I agree with you new users cannot be discerned but I expected to be able to override the property in application.properties.
As you suggested, I created a bug report:
https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/10359